# Can I have a component that doesn't render a pseudo-element?

Tags: angular, angular-components

I'm trying to create a set of components that will allow me to render a table, where the "user" only needs to provide:

- the data (a 2-d array)
- a cell template for each column

So, *ideally*, you might use these components to render a 3-column table like so:

```
<app-table [data]='sampleData'>
  <td>{{cell.toString().toUpperCase()}}</td>
  <td class="myClass">{{cell}}</td>
  <app-cell [cell]="cell"></app-cell>
</app-table>
```

...the idea being that the `app-table` component would render the three `app-column` components *for every row*, and magically provide the cell value to each column as `cell`. The user of the component then has full control over how each column is rendered - including what classes are applied to the `td` tag, etc.

I've not had much luck trying to achieve this. The best I've come up with so far can be seen in [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iyf729), where I have an `app-table` component that renders the `tr`, and which expects its content to include one `ng-template` for each column. The markup is not nearly as clean as the pseudo-markup above:

```
<app-table [data]='sampleData'>
  <ng-template let-cell="cell"><td>{{cell.toString().toUpperCase()}}</td></ng-template>
  <ng-template let-cell="cell"><td class="myClass">{{cell}}</td></ng-template>
  <ng-template let-cell="cell"><td><app-cell [data]="cell"></app-cell></td></ng-template>
</app-table>
```

It's a bit ugly because of all the extra markup required to pass the data down into the template, but that's not the biggest problem.

You'll notice that the last "column" uses an `app-cell` component, but that component is still wrapped inside a `td` tag:

```
<ng-template let-cell="cell">
  <td>
    <app-cell [data]="cell"></app-cell>
  </td>
</ng-template>
```

That's not really what I wanted: I'd like the `app-cell` component to provide the `td` tag itself, since otherwise it can't (for example) set classes on that element.

Currently, the `app-cell` component has a `HostBinding` that adds a class ("foo"), but that gets added to the `app-cell` element itself, not to the `td` element where it's needed:

```
<td>
  <app-cell class="foo">
    <div>...</div>
  </app-cell>
</td>
```

The obvious thing to do is to move the `td` tag into the `app-cell` component, but if I [do that](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qxse3f), then the rendered HTML looks like this:

```
<app-cell class="foo">
  <td>
    <div>...</div>
  </td>
</app-cell>
```

[OK, so the class is still applied in the wrong place, but it's easy to see how to move it down to the `td` tag.]

However, that extra pseudo-element sitting between the `tr` and `td` elements worries me - the browser I'm using doesn't seem to mind, but I suspect that much of my CSS is going to be thrown by it, because there are selectors that expect the `td` to be a direct child of the `tr`.

Is there a way to get rid of that extra pseudo-element? Ordinarily I might look at using a directive, but I don't see how I can do that here, because the `app-cell` component needs a template, and directives don't have those...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These types of components are my favorite. At the end of the day, you want something like following assuming you have a data like this

```
carData = [{
   model: 'Mercedes',
   year: 2015,
   km: 10000
}, {
   model: 'Audi',
   year: 2016,
   km: 5000
}];
```

And you want to display first two columns as is and for the last one you want to display some custom template.

```html
<app-table [data]="carData">
   <app-cell header="Model" field="model"></app-cell>
   <app-cell header="Year" field="year"></app-cell>
   <app-cell header="Km" field="km" styleClass="km-cell">
      <ng-template custom-cell-body let-car>
          {{car.km | number}} km
      </ng-template>
   </app-cell>
</app-table>
```

Here is what you can do, (I got this trick out of Angular Material and Primeng which works just fine)

You can find a working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bptf7b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-table.component.ts)

First define a directive for custom body templates for cells. (You can do the same thing for headers as well)

```js
@Directive({selector: '[custom-cell-body]'})
export class AppCellBodyTemplate {
  constructor(public template: TemplateRef<any>) {}
}
```

And let's define our `AppCellComponent`

`app-cell.component.ts`

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-cell',
  template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`
})
export class AppCellComponent {
  @Input() header;
  @Input() field;
  @Input() styleClass;

  @ContentChild(AppCellBodyTemplate) customBody: AppCellBodyTemplate;
}
```

Let's glue them all together at `AppTableComponent`

`app-table.component.ts`

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  templateUrl: './app-table.component.html' 
})
export class AppTableComponent {
  @Input() data: any[];

  @ContentChildren(AppCellComponent) cells: QueryList<AppCellComponent>;
}
```

`app-table.component.html`

```html
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <!-- loop through cells and create header part of the table -->
        <ng-container *ngFor="let cell of cells">
          <th>{{cell.header}}</th>
        </ng-container>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let row of data">
        <!-- loop through cells -->
        <ng-container *ngFor="let cell of cells">
          <td [ngClass]="cell.styleClass">
            <!-- if cell has a custom body, render that -->
            <ng-container *ngIf="cell.customBody; else defaultBody">
              <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="cell.customBody.template;
                context: {$implicit: row}">
              </ng-container>
            </ng-container>
            <!-- else render default cell body -->
            <ng-template #defaultBody>{{row[cell.field]}}</ng-template>
          </td>
        </ng-container>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Here are some points needed to be explained.

- `template: TemplateRef<any>` within `AppCellBodyTemplate`
  Since, we are going to use `custom-body-cell` with `ng-template`s all the time, we can get a reference of the template defined within. This `template` will be used within `*ngTemplateOutlet`
- `@ContentChild(AppCellBodyTemplate) customBody` within `AppCellComponent` is to detect whether there is a `custom-body-cell` defined as `ContentChild`
- `@ContentChildren(AppCellComponent) cells: QueryList<AppCellComponent>` is to get instance of `cells` (you did the similar thing).
- `context: {$implicit: row}` is to expose some data to the consumers of this component. `$implicit` makes you enable to retrieve this context with any template variable you want. Since, I used `$implicit` here, I was able to do this `<ng-template custom-cell-body let-car>` Otherwise, I would have to define my `car` variable something like this `let-car="rowData"`

Comment: I like the look of that. As usual with anything Angular, It'll take me several hours to figure out what the heck is going on (and google the stuff I've not seen before - looking at you `$implicit`, but at first glance it looks good! Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. I'll explain small details with comments.

Comment: @GaryMcGill added some more explanation

Comment: One of the things that puzzled me about this was the need for the AppCellBodyTemplate directive, which seems to do very little. I wondered why that was necessary, and have attempted to re-do your example without it. See [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1ytbrw). It seems to work - do you think I'll lose any functionality with that approach?

Comment: In the future, you'll need another template for customizing headers (I've developed a table component myself). When you do need that, you will have to select different templates with different queries. Until then, yours seems just fine.

Comment: Yeah, I can see that it might be useful to specify *which* template, but even then it should be possible to do that with a template name (#header or #body) rather than a directive? (You can specify `@ContentChild("header")` to select the right one.

Comment: @GaryMcGill you are actually right, your way does not require a directive. I think, If you need to pass some attributes with `body` or `header` templates, then it might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question - because I found [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53613070/can-i-have-a-component-that-doesnt-render-a-pseudo-element) in the "related" sidebar: I can use an attribute selector rather than an element selector.

This [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-izp4vr) shows the results.

Comment: But, you'd still have to write `td` within your templates. I'll post a better way to achieve this.